# Puppeteer: screenshots in headless Chromium result in blocky gradients

Tags: puppeteer, chromium, google-chrome-headless, webpage-screenshot, puppeteer-sharp

I have a web page with a linear gradient

`background: linear-gradient(180deg, #7e7e7e 0%, #454545 100%);`

When I take a PNG screenshot with PuppeteerSharp, it looks fine.

However, if I enable headless mode, the gradient looks really blocky, as if color precision is lost when applying gamma correction, or like jpeg compression color quantization...

I tried passing the `--force-color-profile` argument, and that results in different colors, but the blocks remain.

Does anyone know how to improve the quality of Puppeteer screenshots with gradients?

Comment: I debugged this a bit, and it seems the non-headless version applies dithering to the gradient, and the headless  version doesn't.